# Laravel: "Could not open imput file: artisan". O que pode ser?

Tags: php, android, laravel, composer

Estou aprendendo a usar o Laravel e estava baixando o Composer. Instalei via programa, tudo ok, mas na hora de instalar o Laravel e testar o php artisan serve, aparece isso na imagem. Me parece estar instalado mas não sei o que acontece, não entendo muito disso e quase não encontrei casos parecidos. Eu uso o Ampps

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já criou o projeto usando `laravel new <nome>`?

Comment: C:\Users\DZ>laravel new appLaravel
Crafting application...

In CurlFactory.php line 185:

  cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcu
  rl-errors.html)


new [--dev] [--force] [--] [<name>]                  

Assim?

Comment: Esse comentário não ajuda em nada. Por favor, melhore a sua pergunta adicionando mais detalhes. Procure também ler a documentação [referente à instalação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation).

Comment: pelo jeito o seu projeto esta na pasta `appLaravel` da um `cd appLaravel` (nao sei como é no windows) e depois roda o `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Requerimentos para a instalação:**

- PHP >= 7.1.3
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension
- Ctype PHP Extension
- JSON PHP Extension
- BCMath PHP Extension

**1º Passo,** se você ainda não tiver o php instalado em sua maquina aconselho utilizar o [laragon](https://laragon.org/download/index.html) ele facilita o desenvolvimento de aplicações WEB instalando tudo o que você ira precisa para ter um servidor localhost configurado para desenvolvimento.

**2º Passo,** Instalar Composer você pode encontrar [aqui](https://getcomposer.org/)

**3º Passo,** Baixar o instalador laravel com esse comando

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

**4º Passo,** agora você pode instalar o laravel em qualquer diretório de sua escolha com o comando

```
laravel new nomeDaAplicação
```

Ou

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.7.*"
```

**5º Passo,** no diretorio onde você instalou o laravel com o **4º passo,** você deve rodar o comando `php artisan serve` Agora você pode começar modificar os arquivos para construir seus sistema.

Comment: Foi tudo ok até o 4o passo, no 4o passo deu esse erro

  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Project directory blog/ is not empty.

Comment: é por que no diretorio `/blog` já existe ua app laravel digite `cd blog` para entrar no diretório blog através do `CMD` depois digite `php artisan serve`

Comment: Warning: require_once(C:\Users\DZ\blog\vendor/composer/autoload_real.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\DZ\blog\vendor\autoload.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\DZ\blog\vendor/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\DZ\blog\vendor\autoload.php on line 5

Já é um progresso, pelo menos mudou de mensagem

Comment: Atá está faltando as dependências da vendor digite `composer update` se não der certo digite `composer dump-autoload` se der certo avisa aqui...

Comment: Cara deu certo. Muito obrigado. Eu não sabia da parte da pasta blog nem do composer update. Vlw de vdd :)

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive o mesmo problema na hora de mandar para o GIT , pois a pasta vendor não estava indo e fiquei horas quabrando a cabeça, ai uma amiga resolveu o problema informando que tem que enviar a pasta vendor.
Pronto feito o download da Pasta vendor para o projeto não precisou de mais nenhuma configuração e resolveu o problema.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).